# How would I check if the client is no longer connected via TCP in Java?

Tags: java, tcp

I'm making a server/client test and want to know if the client is disconnected in java via TCP.
I'd rather not do a heartbeat but if I have to, I will.

Answer (score 1):

You have a thread reading from client as a socket input stream. The read may return EOF (-1) if connection is closed by client. Also error could be thrown if there's network problems. In either case you can assume client is disconnected.

Comment: I did it by simply reading and surrounding it in try. Thanks.